# Laravel boolean validation based on others column

Tags: laravel, validation, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to validate the `is_default` column based on `domain_id`. The condition is for every `domain_id` there can be only one(single) `1`; others multiple will be `0 (zero)`.

I try to make a rule in Laravel that's like the following. But It's not working; I know it's wrong. So what would be the best query?

```
$query = Restaurant::where($attribute, $value)
    ->where('domain_user.domain_id', request()->get('domain_id'));
```

[image]

Comment: What does the request look like? Add an example. Do you edit each row separately or multiple rows in one request?

Comment: Multiple request in one time. `domain_id` column will not be update.

Comment: So actually whenever you update you want to make sure that there is only 1 DEFAULT for every domain id, right? And what is your $query for? @MaheKarim

Comment: Yes, only 1 DEFAULT for every domain id @AleksandarĐokić

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you might want:

```
function updateDefault($domain_id, $name) {
    //updating default domain with given name
    Restoraunt::where('domain_id',$domain_id)->where('name', $name)->first()->update(['is_default' => 1]);
  
    //setting all other models with same domain_id to 0
    Restoraunt::where('domain_id', $domain_id)->where('name', '!=', $name)->update(['is_default' => 0]);
  
}
```

[image]

If you for example use `updateDefault(1, 'ABC - 2')` results would be :
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help. I don't want to write in controller section. Is there any way to make it with laravel validation or laravel rule based validation ? @Aleksandar

Comment: Use that logic to make custom rule https://www.esparkinfo.com/laravel-custom-validation-rules.html